# prove that a function isn't continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

let's say
$$A=\{ f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R | f \text{ is differentiable at } [-1,1]\},$$
$$C=\{f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R| f \text{ is differentiable and } f' \text{ is continuous at }[-1,1]\}$$
I wanted to prove that $A$ doesn't imply $C$.

I had this counter example in mind:
$$f:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R,\quad f(x)= \begin{cases}x^{2}\sin(1/x), & x\neq0 \\ 0, & x=0 .\end{cases}$$
Then
$$f':[-1,1]\to\Bbb R,\quad \begin{cases}2x\sin(1/x)+\cos(1/x),  & x\neq0 \\ 0, & x=0 .\end{cases}$$

I tried to prove that $f'$ isn't continuous but I'm stuck.

I started with this: Take a  random $a\in [-1,1]$.

We're looking for an $\epsilon>0$ such that for a random $\delta>0$ and a fixed $x \in [-1,1]$, so that $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(a)|>\epsilon$.

I tried a lot finding that $\epsilon$, but without success.

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm just trying to understand the math that I'm doing and i thougt that my message was easy enough to read without the big {

Comment: I changed it , hope it's better now

Comment: A general principle is that when asking others to expend effort to help with math, there should first been some proportional effort to make your question is clearly written, typo-free, proper MathJax, etc. Some general tips: (1) spell check, e.g. "contiuous". (2) Use standard terminology, e.g., what does "$f$ is derivative at $[-1,1]$" mean? (3) Use fewer dollar signs in latex and put *all math symbols* in dollar signs e.g., write `$A=\{....\}$` instead of `$A$={$...$}`. (4) Use `\mid` instead of `|` for the "such that" bar in sets (the former adds space).

Comment: (5) If you are trying to write a symbol, there is probably a tex command for it, e.g., `\rightarrow` instead of `->`. (6) Use special fonts for special sets, e.g., $R$ could be anything; you want $\mathbb{R}$. (7) Use latex for *all math* instead of copypasting special symbols. (8) Use spacing to make things clear, e.g., put your definitions of $A$ and $C$ on separate lines.

Comment: @mathmath, the derivative is wrong. It should be $2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$. If you want to find a counter example, i.e. to disprove continuity, it is often easier to apply the definition of continuity which is based on sequences. So all you need to do is find/construct a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n= 0$ with $f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n)\neq 0$. __Hint__: Try to use $\pi$ in your sequence.

Comment: Are u sure about my derivative that's wrong. Because i thought the second term was -cos(1/x)(-1/$x^{2}$)$x^{2}$?

Comment: @mathmath, yes I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

It should be intuitively clear that, in $\:2x\sin(1/x)+\cos(1/x)$, the first term tends to $0$ when $x$ tends to $0$, whereas the second term has no limit.

So try to define a first sequence $(x_n)$ which tends to $0$ such that the second term is always equal to $1$, and a second sequence such that the second term is always $0$, or $-1$, or whatever you want between $-1$ and $1$.

Explicitly, for instance, $\cos1/x=1=\cos 0\iff 1/x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi$, i.e. $1/x=2n\pi$ for some $n$, or $x=1/2n\pi$.

Comment: can I use two times the sequence ($x_{n})$=$1/xn$

Comment: This willyield for the second term $\cos(nx)$, of which you can't say much, not knowing $x$. Most  of the times, the cosine will be dense in $ [-1,1]$. It is better to look for a sequence $(y_n)$ tending  to $\infty$ and such that $\cos y_n$ is constant, then set $x_n=\frac1{y_n}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if i got it. Is a good $y_{n}$ then $nx$?

Comment: No, not $nx$. I mean determine $\frac 1{x_n}$ so the cosine is constant, then deduce $x_n$ (tending to $0$ if $\frac 1{x_n}\to\infty$). Is it clearer?

Comment: Yeah i think i get what you mean, but i'm feeling really stupid but can come up with any function that makes cosine constant ( beside the constant functions)

Comment: Can't you solve, say, $\cos x=1$?

Comment: yes arccos(1), but that's 0?

Comment: This is not explicit. If you're accustomed to using the trigonometric circle, you can have instantly the general solution.